# How to copy data from On-Premise Oracle to Azure SQL Database

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-sql-database

Is there any way to move the data from Oracle to Azure SQL Databases? We need to do 1 time migrations our database sizes are not so huge in size can ADF be the best option here, can we directly restore on-premise oracle database to azure sql databases?

Comment: It's in the docs https://datamigration.microsoft.com/scenario/oracle-to-azuresqldb?step=1

Comment: The answer provided by @isalgueiro is the best option to my knowledge

Comment: Hi,if my answer helps, could please accept(mark) or vote it? Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Oracle to migrate your Oracle data or database to Azure SQL database.

SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Oracle is a comprehensive environment that helps you quickly migrate Oracle databases to SQL Server, Azure SQL DB, or Azure SQL Data Warehouse. By using SSMA for Oracle, you can review database objects and data, assess databases for migration, migrate database objects to SQL Server, Azure SQL DB, or Azure SQL Data Warehouse, and then migrate data to SQL Server, Azure SQL DB, or Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Please see this Azure tutorial: [Migrating Oracle Databases to SQL Server(OracleToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/migrating-oracle-databases-to-sql-server-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017). Just need to follow the tutorial and migrate your Oracle data to Azrue SQL database.

You also can reference tutorial isalgueiro provide for you: [Migrate Oracle to Azure SQL Database](https://datamigration.microsoft.com/scenario/oracle-to-azuresqldb?step=1).

Hope this helps.